# Checking a List over and over again to see if an index exists?

Tags: c#

I have a `List<String>` named `record` with a possible max `Count` of 102. I need to pull 50 of the elements and add them as query parameters. However, all 50 may not exist, and if not then I need to add the parameter as a `DBNull.Value`. The following works, but is there a better way than checking to see if the index exists each time?

```
List<String> record = new List<String>(myRecord.ToString().Split(new string[] { "^" }, StringSplitOptions.None));

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO myTable ([Field1], [Field3], [Field7], [Field9]"
+ ") VALUES ("
+ "@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4)"

if (record.ElementAtOrDefault(1) != null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", record[1]);
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", DBNull.Value);
}

if (record.ElementAtOrDefault(3) != null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", record[3]);
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", DBNull.Value);
}

if (record.ElementAtOrDefault(7) != null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", record[7);
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", DBNull.Value);
}

if (record.ElementAtOrDefault(9) != null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", record[9]);
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", DBNull.Value);
}

....
....repeat this for @p5 thru @p50
....

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

**The working solution is as follows:**

```
var indexes = new List<int> { 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 32, 33, 35, 36, 38, 39, 44, 45, 46, 49, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 62, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83 };

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO myTable ([Field1], [Field3], [Field7], [Field9]"
+ ") VALUES ("
+ "@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4)"    

List<String> record = new List<String>(myRecord.ToString().Split(new string[] { "^" }, StringSplitOptions.None));

var records = record.Where((item, index) => indexes.Contains(index)).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    string paramName = "@p" + (i);

    if (i <= records.Count-1)      //index starts with a 0 
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, (object)records[(i)] ?? DBNull.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, DBNull.Value);
    }
}

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

Comment: I would loop it, but the `record[count]` and parameter name aren't always the same, and I don't need to check ALL items in the list.

Comment: Then store the mapping between indices and parameter names in a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: excellent idea .. that is the type of feedback i was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you accessing your elements by index,then maybe you can store your indexes into a `List`:

```
var indexes = new List<int> { 1, 3, 7, 9 ... };
```

Then get your elements:

```
var records = record.Where((item,index) => indexes.Contains(index)).ToList();
```

Then use a `for` loop (instead of your if statements)

```
for(int i=1; i<records.Count; i++)
{  
   string paramName = "@p" + i;
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, records[i] ?? DBNull.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. this works unless `records.Count` is less than the number of parameters. I'm seeing if it works by changing to `for(int i=1; i<51; i++);` and putting a check to see if `records[i]` exists, and if not, then set the parameter to `DBNull.Value`

Comment: This worked .. thank you! I just had to include the check mentioned in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Totally untested and may contain bugs/typos, but generally, I'd do:

```
void ParseMyList(string[] myRecord)
{
    List<String> record = new List<String>(myRecord.ToString().Split(new string[] { "^" }, StringSplitOptions.None));
    Dictionary<int, string> paramLookup = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    paramLookup.Add(1, "@p1");
    paramLookup.Add(3, "@p2");
    paramLookup.Add(7, "@p3");
    paramLookup.Add(9, "@p4");
    /*
    ....
    ....repeat this for @p5 thru @p50
    ....
    */

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO myTable ([Field1], [Field3], [Field7], [Field9]"
        + ") VALUES ("
        + "@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4)"

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> entry in paramLookup)
    {
        if (record.ElementAtOrDefault(entry.Value))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(entry.Value, record[entry.Key]);
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(entry.Value, DBNull.Value);
        }
    }

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
}
```